# Accessing OPC DA Server using .NET remoting

Tags: c#, vb.net, remoting, opc

I have written a small OPC.DA client using OPCNetApi library where I can view items in a DA Server.
I notice that the server and DA items implement remoting capabilities.

OPC.DAServer(UseRemoting);
And the Opc.DA.Item(SerializationContext context);

What I would like to know is how do I use Remoting with the OPCNetAPI, a small example of browsing and monitoring in C# or Vb.NET - short sweet and to the point would be nice.

**EDIT**
For the down voters and possibly others.
I am not asking about how to connect to a remote DA server - I can do that! 
This question pertains to remoting with the OpcNetApi.dll , how to use that library to accomplish remoting to acquire and monitor values in an OPC Server .
I can't post all of the NON-Links to this, there is a heck of a lot dealing with OPC.DA on SO but nothing that addresses remoting with the Opc.DA. Server in that context. using search engines google, bing, yahoo and others to hunt it down does not show any examples either.